Compose UI Tapping on 2nd textfield is resetting the 1st textfield value BasicTextField2
Attached the view video clip and below is working code and please import the necessary library
tapping on 2nd text field is resetting the first text field value with initial state value
Upload the video on YouTube as unlisted please check .
New to compose UI ,Sorry if it's a basic question
video link for the issue
@Composable
fun SignupScreen() {
Log.d("Recomposition", "SignupScreen is recomposing")
Scaffold { innerPadding ->
    val nameTextField by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("reset 1")
    }
    val emailTextField by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("reset 2")
    }
    Column(
        Modifier
            .padding(innerPadding)
            .onGloballyPositioned {
                Log.d("Recomposition", "MyComposable layout changed")
            }
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,

            ) {

            CustomTextField(textFieldValue = nameTextField, label = "Your name") { value ->
                val returnValue: String? = if (value.length < 5) {
                    "Name is short"
                } else {
                    null
                }
                returnValue
            }
            CustomTextField(textFieldValue = emailTextField, label = "Your email") { value ->
                val emailRegex = "^[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$".toRegex()
                val returnValue: String? = if (emailRegex.matches(value)) {
                    null
                } else {
                    "invalid email address"
                }
                returnValue
            }
        }
    }

}
}
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
textFieldValue: String,
label: String,
validator: ((String) -> String?)? = null
 ) {
  Log.d("Recomposition", "MyComposable is recomposing")
var errorString by rememberSaveable {
    mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
}

BasicTextField2(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 10.dp),
    value = textFieldValue,
    onValueChange = { value ->
        validator?.let {
            errorString = validator(value)
        }
    },
    cursorBrush = SolidColor(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
    textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 18.sp),
    decorator = { innerTextField ->
        Column {
            Text(
                text = label,
                color = if (errorString == null) Color.Black else Color.Red,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
            )
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            innerTextField()
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(7.dp))
            HorizontalDivider(color = if (errorString == null) DividerDefaults.color else Color.Red)
            if (errorString != null) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(end = 5.dp),
                    text = errorString!!,
                    color = Color.Red,
                    fontSize = 13.sp,
                    textAlign = TextAlign.End
                )
            }
        }
    }
)

}

Ignore this. Adding few words just to avoid stock overflow error for less description

I added an answer below. If you found it useful, please mark it as accepted answer by clicking the checkmark at the left side of the answer. Thank you!

I'm answering my question , with some ideas
after saving the values from callBack of onValueChanged the textfield state is not resetting while tapping on other textfield ,
for other textfield onValueChanged is mandatory but for BasicTextField2 is not and also BasicTextField2 update it's UI without onValueChanged callback -> it tends to do like this to improve the performance but when we tap other textfield it's resting the value as it can hold only one text value instance
I'm not sure whether my explanation is correct . please correct me if I wrong

You are mixing different overloads of the BasicTextField. What surprises me is that your code compiles in the first place.
First, please make sure that you use the latest Compose Foundation Library:
implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.7.0-rc01"

Also update all other Compose dependencies simultaneously.
In the latest Compose version, the BasicTextField2 was renamed to BasicTextField. So in total, we now have three BasicTextField overloads:

BasicTextField offering a value: String, onValueChange: (String) -> Unit
BasicTextField offering a value: TextFieldValue, onValueChange: (TextFieldValue) -> Unit
BasicTextField offering a state: TextFieldState based upon BasicTextField2

So when you want to use the newest BasicTextField overload based on BasicTextField2, you need to pass a TextFieldState to the CustomTextField Composable like this:
@Composable
fun SignupScreen() {
    Log.d("Recomposition", "SignupScreen is recomposing")
    Scaffold { innerPadding ->
        val nameTextField = remember {
            TextFieldState("reset 1")
        }
        val emailTextField = remember {
            TextFieldState("reset 2")
        }
        Column(
            //...
        ) {
            Column(
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,

                ) {

                CustomTextField(textFieldValue = nameTextField, label = "Your name") { value ->
                    val returnValue: String? = if (value.length < 5) {
                        "Name is short"
                    } else {
                        null
                    }
                    returnValue
                }
                CustomTextField(textFieldValue = emailTextField, label = "Your email") { value ->
                    val emailRegex = "^[A-Za-z0-9+_.-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$".toRegex()
                    val returnValue: String? = if (emailRegex.matches(value)) {
                        null
                    } else {
                        "invalid email address"
                    }
                    returnValue
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun CustomTextField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    textFieldValue: TextFieldState,
    label: String,
    validator: (String) -> String?
) {
    Log.d("Recomposition", "MyComposable is recomposing")
    var errorString by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf<String?>(null)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(textFieldValue.text) {
        if (textFieldValue.undoState.canUndo) {
            errorString = validator(textFieldValue.text.toString())
        }
    }

    BasicTextField(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(horizontal = 20.dp, vertical = 10.dp),
        state = textFieldValue,
        cursorBrush = SolidColor(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
        textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 18.sp),
        decorator = { innerTextField ->
            Column {
                Text(
                    text = label,
                    color = if (errorString == null) Color.Black else Color.Red,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
                )
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
                innerTextField()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(7.dp))
                HorizontalDivider(color = if (errorString == null) DividerDefaults.color else Color.Red)
                if (errorString != null) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .padding(end = 5.dp),
                        text = errorString!!,
                        color = Color.Red,
                        fontSize = 13.sp,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.End
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    )
}

We use a LaunchedEffect to retrigger the validator function whenever the text changes. As you probably don't want any errors to be shown immediately before the user changed anything, you can use the canUndo boolean. It becomes true once the text has changed for the first time.
The validator function does not need to be nullable. I changed it from
validator: ((String) -> String?)? = null

to
validator: (String) -> String?

Note that it is a good practice to store the TextFieldState and a validation Flow inside a ViewModel as described in this blog post.
